# Аналог StartsWith в NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Для работы с Ms SQL используется NHibernate v2.2. При составлении условия с использованием

```
.IsLike("value", MatchMode.Start)
```

генерируется следующий код:

```
like value%
```

В Ms SQL для строк есть стандартная функция StartsWith. Для того, чтобы избежать поиска по строкам, хотелось бы использовать именно её. Возможно ли использование этой функции в NHibernate?

Comment: _В Ms SQL для строк есть стандартная функция StartsWith_ - где? [String Functions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). В упор не вижу.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да, что-то знатно тупанул в плане "стандартной" функции. Но есть, например, left, charindex - так понимаю, что для их использования нужно запрос ручками написать, использовать конструктор запросов не получится?